# Difference of maximum and minimum by group

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
v1  v2  v3
a   2   5
b   5   3
c   2   1
d   2   1
e   1   2
a   2   4
a   8   1
e   1   6
b   0   1
c   2   8
d   1   5
```

using R, I want to compute for every unique value of V1, the difference between the max V3 and the min V3.
Expected :

```
Val max_min
a   “5-1”
b   “3-1”
c   “8-1”
d   “5-1”
e   “6-2”
```

I am trying using

```
 ddply(fil1, c("V1"), summarise,  max(V3) - min(V1))
```

but, don't have the expected result. It gives the same value in max_min: the max(V3) - min(V3) for the whole data frame and not for the group.
I have also try

```
average
```

, with no success.

Comment: For named vector, you could use `tapply` in base R `with(df, tapply(v3, list(v1), function(i) max(i)-min(i)))`.

Comment: Your question seems to be specific about `ddply` and `dplyr` group

Comment: I don't think so. Because base R solutions also work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or in base R,

```
MAX = aggregate(df$v3, list(df$v1), max)
MIN = aggregate(df$v3, list(df$v1), min)
MAX[,2] - MIN[,2]
[1] 4 2 7 4 4
```

A one liner of the above would be,

```
aggregate(v3 ~ v1, df, FUN = function(i)max(i) - min(i))
#  v1 v3
#1  a  4
#2  b  2
#3  c  7
#4  d  4
#5  e  4
```

We can also use `tapply` which will display the output as follows,

```
with(df, tapply(v3, list(v1), function(i) max(i)-min(i)))
#a b c d e 
#4 2 7 4 4
```

Comment: or simply `aggregate(v3 ~ v1, df, FUN = function(i)max(i) - min(i))`

Comment: @Sotos Elegant!

Comment: I edited to add the `tapply` as well (as shown by @lmo in comments). Hope you don't mind

Comment: No problem.  I like to promote base R solutions and both additions are good ones.   Mine was intended to be transparent for beginners, but these are helpful.

Comment: You can also post my solutions in your post.

Comment: @akrun I can no longer see your post.  It was helpful.  Please undelete.

Comment: @GSW Its okay.  I deleted it due to some comments

Answer (score 0):

You could also go for `split`:

```
lapply(split(df$v3, df$v1), function(a) max(a)-min(a))

# $a
# [1] 4

# $b
# [1] 2

# $c
# [1] 7

# $d
# [1] 4

# $e
# [1] 4
```

In case you persist to see your defined output:

```
ls <- lapply(split(df$v3, df$v1), function(a) max(a)-min(a))
data.frame(Val=names(ls), max_min=unlist(ls))

#  Val max_min
#a   a       4
#b   b       2
#c   c       7
#d   d       4
#e   e       4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) you can use the `summarise` function. In base R, `range` returns a vector containing the min and max values, and `diff` finds the difference. So a one-liner is:

```
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarise(max_min=diff(range(V3)))
```